# returning an object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, storage

I have an array of objects;

```
var rivers = [
  { name: "Amazon", continent: "South America", lengthInKilometers: 6575 },
  { name: "Danube", continent: "Europe", lengthInKilometers: 2850 },
  { name: "Ganges", continent: "Asia", lengthInKilometers: 2704 },
  { name: "Mekong", continent: "Asia", lengthInKilometers: 4350 },
  { name: "Mississippi", continent: "North America" },
  { name: "Nile", continent: "Africa", lengthInKilometers: 6650 },
  { name: "Volga", continent: "Europe", lengthInKilometers: 3530 },
];
```

I want write a function, this function expects a string as an argument and returns
the object in the rivers array whose name property is equal to the
string that is passed to it (if there is one).

```
function getRiverByName(strTest) {
  let answer = rivers.filter(function (river) {
    return river.name === strTest;
  });
  return answer;
}
```

How to store the output of this function, which is an array into an object
can i do something like this?

```
    function getRiverByName(strTest) {
  
     var obj = {
        let answer=rivers.filter(function(river){
        return river.name===strTest;
    })
      }
       return obj; 
   }
```

Comment: do you always want to return one object or cam there be multiple records returned?

Comment: @YakirAvraham Please mark an answer as the solution if it solves the problem to close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```js
var rivers =[
  {name: "Amazon", continent: "South America", lengthInKilometers: 6575},
  {name: "Danube", continent: "Europe", lengthInKilometers: 2850},
  {name: "Ganges", continent: "Asia", lengthInKilometers: 2704},
  {name: "Mekong", continent: "Asia", lengthInKilometers: 4350},
  {name: "Mississippi", continent: "North America"},
  {name: "Nile", continent: "Africa", lengthInKilometers: 6650},
  {name: "Volga", continent: "Europe", lengthInKilometers: 3530}
];

function getRiverByName(strTest) {
  let answer = rivers.find(function(river){
    return river.name===strTest;
  });
  return answer;
}

console.log(getRiverByName("Volga"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A compressed version:

```
const getRiverByName = (strTest) => rivers.find( r => r.name === strTest)
```